# What free Delphi component can you recommend for reading an email and an attachment?

Tags: delphi, email, delphi-7

What free Delphi component can you recommend for reading an email and an attachment?

I mean reading an email from pop3 server.

I use Delphi 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start by trying [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org)'s [TIdPop3](http://www.kumanov.com/docs/prog/indy/007617.html) component. I think it's  shipped as standard with most Delphi versions.

Comment: Consider first upgrading your Indy Version.  I can't recall which one is shipped with Delphi 7, but it's old enough to deserve a upgrade.  You'll also avoid Indy 9 to Indy 10 conversion.

Comment: Delphi 6, and I think also 7, shipped with Indy 8.  The latest Indy 9 release was 9.0.50, and then current Indy 10 release is 10.5.8.

Comment: And here http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:whysynapse is the reason, why I recommend Synapse.

Answer (score 2):

Try Synapse from Lukas Gebauer. Actually it's not a component, it's just a set of units, which you simply add to your uses list. It's simple, stable and verified by many users.
Check these links ...

[Synapse - download page](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download)
[Synapse - tutorials page](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public%3ahowto)
[Synapse - POP3 simple example](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public%3ahowto%3apop3sample)

Comment: I cannot see how Synapse can be used to save attachments easily

Comment: Ok, but attachments are quite difficult stuff. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME. And whatever you'll use, it will be just wrap of this logic. And in Synapse is this issue at least on 4 lines of code, what is sufficient at least for me :)